# Use states and functions of a component in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have two separate component and they do not have parent child relation (I cannot render component B in component A) so I cannot write  and pass props to it. Is there a separate way to use component A's states and functions in component B?
I am a bit confused since I am a beginner.

Comment: Are you using redux in your app ?

Comment: well if they both have the same father they can use Context api

Comment: I have'nt used redux. So if both components are rendered in App component will I be able to share component A's state and functions in component B? Or just create context in B and use its states in A?

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand they have both the same father so
look at Context API that way you wrap the father and then both of them will have the same state and function you pass.

[context API official doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and used the [use-global-hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-global-hook) npm package.

[Here](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/state-management-with-react-hooks-no-redux-or-context-api-8b3035ceecf8) is an article with an example on how to use it:

And here is a section from the article that may be of interest:

[image]

This is just a personal preference, but I try to avoid context API if possible. [Here](https://leewarrick.com/blog/the-problem-with-context/) is an article outlining its pitfalls